# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, scss-lint

I am working on angular 8 project and was trying to add page screen overlay but facing ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. I have added button, on which I m making style.display = 'none' OR 'block'. My code work properly on Local but after deploying on firebase using "ng build --prod" I got error.
Here are my files

index.html file

```
    <div id="loader-overlay">
      <div class="spinner-container">
        <div class="loader"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Styles.scss File

```
#loader-overlay-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000000;
  top:0;
}

#loader-overlay {
  display: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

shared.service.ts

```
 // To ADD Page loader screen
  enablePageLoaderOverlay() { 
    document.getElementById('loader-overlay').style.display = 'block';
  }

  // To REMOVE Page loader screen
  disablePageLoaderOverlay() {
    document.getElementById('loader-overlay').style.display = 'none';
  }
```

booking.component.ts

```
onBookService(name: string) {

    // To ADD Page loader screen
    this.sharedService.enablePageLoaderOverlay();

    this.sharedCartService.addToCart(this.services[name], "book");
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting element in `document.getElementById('loader-overlay')` ? try to debug or console it.

Comment: Consider other ways to achieve this without using `document.getElementById`. Since you are using angular you can simply use `*ngIf` to show and hide the loader

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you have your DOM-elements in the index.html file.

working stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6286ot?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
<button (click)="hide()">Hide</button>
<button (click)="show()">Show</button>

<div id="loader-overlay">
  <div class="spinner-container">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

--

```
  hide(): void {
    document.getElementById("loader-overlay").style.display = "none";
  }

  show(): void {
    document.getElementById("loader-overlay").style.display = "block";
  }
```

---

However, I would recommend using ViewChild instead of searching with getElementById.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

This is the WRONG way to use Angular... instead it should be

```
<div *ng-if='IsLoaderShown">
    <div class="spinner-container">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your code:

```
IsLoaderShown = true;

hide(): void {
    this.IsLoaderShown = false;
}

show(): void {
    this.IsLoaderShown = true;
}
```